# auto log java exceptions

Tags: java, exception, logging

I have written a huge Web-Application and 'forgot' to include logging (I only print the errors with the standard e.printStackTrace() method).

**My question is, if there is any method to auto-log (getLogger.LOG(SEVERE,"...")) any thrown exception?**

maybe with a custom exception-factory like in [exceptionFactory JSF](http://ovaraksin.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/global-handling-of-all-unchecked.html)?

I want to log every thrown exception with my logger, e.g. before the program enters the catch-block, the exception has to be logged already:

```
try{
...
} catch(Exception1 e){
  //Exception must have been already logged here (without adding getLogger().LOG(...) every time)
  System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());
} catch(Exception2 e){
 //Exception must have been already logged here (without adding getLogger().LOG(...) every time)
  System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());
}
```

Comment: can you give some details of your configuration? do you use spring ?

Comment: hi, no spring, just the good ol' Logger with its Logging-Levels.

Comment: its the same problem with all local-running java apps (with are not web applications). I relied to much on system.out which is not available most of the times

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) which can insert logging code at runtime for your favorite logging framework.  The JDK includes the [java.lang.instrument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) package which can insert bytecodes during classloading to perform your logging.

Otherwise, you can install a servlet [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) as the top most filter in the call chain which will catch most of your exceptions.

```
public class LogFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

private static final String CLASS_NAME = LogFilter.class.getName();
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CLASS_NAME);

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    logger.entering(CLASS_NAME, "doFilter", new Object[]{request, response});
    try {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (IOException | ServletException | RuntimeException | Error ioe) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "", ioe);
        throw ioe; //Keep forwarding.
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "", t);
        throw new ServletException(t);
    }
    logger.exiting(CLASS_NAME, "doFilter");
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}
```

}

Comment: hi, I need a solution which hooks in ALL exceptions (I want to be informed when the application throws any ecxeption)... do you have any other idea?

Comment: Look up 'aspect oriented programming'.

Comment: hi, I am asking how the big players (e.g. facebook) log their failures of the running system? do they just put a Logger.Log(..) on every second line?

Comment: @Niko That sounds like a new question for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can set uncaught exception handler for main thread and every other you create using [Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) method and do all the required logging there.

Comment: When I have a method like: public void doSomething() throws Exception {...}. how can I log the exception automatically?

Comment: I think this would not work, because I have "caught" all my excepions. I just want to send an email when any exception is thrown to inform me

Comment: I'm not sure that what you are trying to accomplish makes sense. If you "forgot" to include logging where it you really need it then it is a design flaw that should be fixed where the problem really exists, not by using workarounds. Note that in any but the simplest applications exceptions happen quite often during normal flow of execution, including standard and any other libraries used. You would end up flooding your mailbox with junk mail if you managed to configure your application this way. That's why there's uncaught exception handler, but no simple way to handle _all_ exceptions.

Comment: so there is no way to intercept extensions? how is ecxeption logging done in big web projects? just Logger.log(...) in every catch clause?

Comment: Exception not always means error condition in an application. Some are part of the possible flow of control that is expected and fully recoverable. I'm not working on web projects (usually), but I think the procedure is mostly the same, log the problem in those catch clauses, where it makes sense form application's point of view. After all, if you catch an exception it makes sense to assume that you take responsibility for it. Uncaught exception handler exists mostly for runtime exceptions and those, that the programmer intentionally skipped by `throws` declarations.

Answer (score 0):

I am now also in front of new larger project and interested in elimination of not necessary code to be produced. First I wanted to log every entry and exit from method including input and output data. In my case of event driven architecture I am pushing these data to elastic and analyse continuously method processing timeouts, that is lot of code lines. So I handled this with AspectJ. Very nice example of this is here:
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-performance-logging

Same applies for auto Error logging, here is dummy example which I will extend to work with slf4j, but these are details:

```
public aspect ExceptionLoggingAspect {

    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());
    private Map loggedThrowables = new WeakHashMap();

    public pointcut scope(): within(nl.boplicity..*);

    after() throwing(Throwable t): scope() {

        logThrowable(t, thisJoinPointStaticPart, 
                thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart);
    }

    before (Throwable t): handler(Exception+) && args(t) && scope() {

        logThrowable(t, thisJoinPointStaticPart, 
                thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart);
    }

    protected synchronized void logThrowable(Throwable t, StaticPart location,
            StaticPart enclosing) {

        if (!loggedThrowables.containsKey(t)) {
            loggedThrowables.put(t, null);

            Signature signature = location.getSignature();

            String source = signature.getDeclaringTypeName() + ":" + 
                (enclosing.getSourceLocation().getLine());

            log.error("(a) " + source + " - " + t.toString(), t);
        }
    }
}
```

I would be happy to hear what else is good example of boiler plate code reduction. I of course use Loombok which does superior task...

**NOTE: do not reinvent wheel**, so look here as other people collected usefull AOP to be reused in your project out of the box :-)) open source is great community: https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-aspects